# C++ How to force prefetch data to cache? (array loop)

Tags: c++, cpu-cache, prefetch

I have loop like this

```
start = __rdtsc();
unsigned long long count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        count += tab[i][j];
stop = __rdtsc();
time = (stop - start) * 1/3;
```

Need to check how prefetch data influences on efficiency.  How to force prefetch some values from memory into cache before they will be counted?

Comment: just check your profiler. probably caching is worse if you switch your for loops.

Comment: Most modern CPUs can handle pre-fetch automatically. You should only issue your own instructions if it's not obvious. Also, pre-fetch instructions aren't exactly portable; each compiler will have its own intrinsics.

Comment: What you are doing is stream processing. I have strong reasons to believe that summing the data in a single cache line takes less time than filling it with data from the main memory and you are actually limited by the available memory bandwidth. I don't see how prefetching (either manual or automatic) could possibly improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I suppose that `tab` is a large  2D array such as a static array (e.g., `int tab[1024*1024][1024*1024]`) or a dynamically-allocated array (e.g., `int** tab` and following `malloc`s). Here, you want to prefetch some data from `tab` to the cache to reduce the execution time.

Simply, I don't think that you need to manually insert any prefetching to your code, where a simple reduction for a 2D array is performed. Modern CPUs will do automatic prefetching if necessary and profitable.

---

Two facts you should know for this problem:

(1) You are already exploit the spatial locality of `tab` inside of the innermost loop. Once `tab[i][0]` is read (after a cache miss, or a page fault), the data from `tab[i][0]` to `tab[i][15]` will be in your CPU caches, assuming that the cache line size is 64 bytes.

(2) However, when the code traverses in the row, i.e., `tab[i][M-1]` to `tab[i+1][0]`, it is highly likely to happen a cold cache miss, especially when `tab` is a dynamically-allocated array where each row could be allocated in a fragmented way. However, if the array is statically allocated, each row will be located contiguously in the memory.

---

So, prefetching makes a sense only when you read (1) the first item of the next row and (2) `j + CACHE_LINE_SIZE/sizeof(tab[0][0])` ahead of time.

You may do so by inserting a prefetch operation (e.g., `__builtin_prefetch`) in the upper loop. However, modern compilers may not always emit such prefetch instructions. If you really want to do that, you should check the generated binary code.

However, as I said, I do *not* recommend you do that because modern CPUs will mostly do prefetching automatically, and that automatic prefetching will mostly outperform your manual code. For instance, an Intel CPU like Ivy Bridge processors, there are multiple data prefetchers such as prefetching to L1, L2, or L3 cache. (I don't think mobile processors have a fancy data prefetcher though). Some prefetchers will load adjacent cache lines.

---

If you do more expensive computations on large 2D arrays, there are many alternative algorithms that are more friendly to caches. A notable example would be **blocked(titled) matrix multiply**. A naive matrix multiplication suffers a lot of cache misses, but a blocked algorithm significantly reduces cache misses by calculating on small subsets that are fit to caches. See some references like [this](http://www.cs.utah.edu/personnel/mb/cs6230mb/week6/matmult2010.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

For GCC only:

```
__builtin_prefetch((const void*)(prefetch_address),0,0);
```

`prefetch_address` can be invalid, there will be no segfault.   If there too small difference between `prefetch_address` and current location, there might be no effect or even slowdown. Try to set it  at least 1k ahead.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest/most portable method is to simply read some data every cacheline bytes apart. Assuming tab is a proper two-dimensional array, you could:

```
char *tptr = (char *)&tab[0][0];
tptr += 64;
char temp;
volatile char keep_temp_alive;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    temp += *tptr;
    tptr += 64;
    for(j = 0; j < M; j++)
        count += tab[i][j];
}
keep_temp_alive = temp;
```

Something like that. However, it does depend on:
 1. You don't end up reading outside the allocated memory [by too much]. 
 2. the J loop is not that much larger than 64 bytes. If it is, you may want to add more steps of `temp += *tptr; tptr += 64;` in the begginning of the loop.

The `keep_temp_alive` after the loop is essential to prevent the compiler from completely removing temp as unnecessary loads.

Unfortunately, I'm too slow writing generic code to suggest the builtin instructions, the points for that goes to Leonid.

Answer (score 2):

The `__builtin_prefetch` instruction is pretty helpful, but is clang/gcc specific. If you are compiling to multiple compiler targets, I had luck using the x86 intrinsic `_mm_prefetch` with both clang and MSVC.

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_prefetch